# how to use rpmbuild for el5 on el6 system

Tags: linux, distributions, rpmbuild

Do any of you have a idea how to build a spec file using rpmbuild for a el5 system while running on el6 host? spec is a simple packaging of py script. Difference between el5 and el6 rpm should by python dependencies (python-json, etc.)

I've tried to use `rpmbuild -bb --target noarch-linux-el5 foo.spec` and simillar, but no luck... :)

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: If it's not proprietary, you could just use the COPR build system.  http://copr.fedoraproject.org/

Answer (score 1):

There are exciting and challenging differences between the rpm-build environment on both systems.

Have you considered mock ?  It's a software project in fedora-land, at https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Mock .  It's apparently /made/ for cross-environment RPM builds.

My own builds are still self-hosted (make EL5 VM, build there, make EL6 VM, build there, etc) but mock is on my own list to check out.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way for me is to create a virtual machines using target distro (el5) in your el6 host. This is just a question of minutes, and the result is certain.

Answer (score 0):

Add these to rpmbuild command line (or even add to .rpmmacros).

```
--define "_source_filedigest_algorithm md5" --define "_binary_filedigest_algorithm md5"
```

I recommend using mock to build for el5 - but you still need el5 compatible SRPMS, so you need to at least make the source_filedigest compatible.

```
$ rpmbuild --define "_source_filedigest_algorithm md5" --define "dist .el5" -bs lbatofile.spec
Wrote: /home/stuart/rpm/SRPMS/lbatofile-0.3-1.el5.src.rpm
$ mock -r epel-5-i386 ../SRPMS/lbatofile*el5*
```